# Selecting groups of cells by condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have an excel sheet like this:

```
Category     Gender      Age    Max male age
A             M          49
              F          38
              F          47
              M          41
B             M          49
              F          38
              F          47
              M          41
```

I want to display the max. male age for each category. The number of people in each category isn't fixed. Is this possible using excel formulas, or do i have to use VBA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by

1. Filling out your categories
2. Using a PivotTable on your date

[image]

**Filling Out Column A**

- Select column A
- Press F5   .... Special
- pick Blanks and hit 'Ok'
- in the formula bar type =A2 (your first category cell)
- hit [cntrl](/questions/tagged/cntrl)[enter](/questions/tagged/enter) together

see Debra Dalgleish'site for a good reference on [this method](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html)

**Insert a PivotTable**
 - Select your data (A1:C9 in my screenshot)
 - Insert .... PivotTable (in Excel 2010)
 - As a `Row` label drag in Category, for `Column` label drag in Gender
 - for`Values` drag in Age, and left click the field and pick `Max`

Again,a good [reference](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot01.html) from Debra

Comment: Really smart use of PivotTables!

Comment: nice gui solution. and that F5 method of filling blank cells was equally awesome, as i had about 150 categories in my sheet

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill the whole category column with values (double-click on the bottom-right of the A2 cell to fill the whole range and so on for every category).
But you will have the max age for every row.

[image]

Formula to add in column D:

```
{=MAX(($A$2:$A$12=A2)*($B$2:$B$12="M")*$C$2:$C$12)}
```

This is an array formula you need to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>